# Migrate with database postgres fails

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I aim to use postgres as default database for my django models. I am using `docker-compose` for the postgres and it seems to be up and running.

```
version: '3.2'
services:

  postgres:
    image: postgres:13.4
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: backend_db
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    volumes:
      - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/ 
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    networks:
      - postgres     

volumes:
  database-data:
    driver: local  

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge
```

However, when I am doing `python3 manage.py migrate --database postgres` I am getting the following:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, authentication, authtoken, contenttypes, sessions, token_blacklist, vpp_optimization
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

The problem is evident also when I am doing `python3 manage.py runserver`, where I am getting:

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 31 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, authentication, authtoken, contenttypes, sessions, token_blacklist, vpp_optimization.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
April 11, 2022 - 05:32:10
Django version 3.1.7, using settings 'core.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

It appears like the command `python3 manage.py migrate --database postgres` was not executed.

Here is the `settings.py` part of the databases:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': get_config(
        'DATABASE_URL',
        'sqlite:///' + BASE_DIR.child('db.sqlite3'),
        cast=db_url
    ),
    'postgres': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': get_config('DB_NAME', 'backend_db'),
        'USER': get_config('DB_USER', 'postgres'),
        'PASSWORD': get_config('DB_PASSWORD', 'postgres'),
        'HOST': get_config('DB_HOST', 'postgres-service'),
        'PORT': get_config('DB_PORT', '5432')
    }
}
```

Any idea of what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you run your migrations against the default DB `python3 manage.py migrate`?

Comment: @IainShelvington No in the above example, but in general yes. The thing is that even if I apply migrate to default database it seems to work, but when I apply it to postgres it says that there are no migrations.

Comment: Maybe the migrations have already been applied to the postgres DB, try dropping the volume `docker-compose down -v` then `docker-compose up -d` and migrating again? If you want to use postgres as your default DB you should configure it as the "default" key in your setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you run:

```
python3 manage.py migrate --database postgres
```

You are explicitly defining that the database where you want to migrate the database schema is in `postgres`. But when you run the app you use:

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

And according to your settings is there anything that indicate that you will use the postgres db. So I think at this point you are usign the `sqlite` db.

One thing that you can do is to setup an env variable to specify which database to use when running the app. Hope it can help.